# XML Parsing and correspondingly screen creation on a blackberry device

Tags: xml, blackberry

I've to parse an incoming XML in a blackberry device and create a dynamic screen based on the XML tags.

I've already done a POC for this using the `net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` and `net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` classes. But I'm not sure of the performance of this POC.

I've the following two questions:

1. Is the above approach performance efficient in production OR Is there is better way of doing this?
2. Are there any tools available to measure the performance of applications on a blackberry device?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the above approach performance
>   efficient in production OR Is there is
>   better way of doing this?

I suppose you are not sending MBytes of XML to create a screen from? So if those XMLs are not too big I would not bother with performance.

However if you'd like to be as fast as possible with parsing you can implement a SAX parser using the classes from `org.xml.sax` package of BB API. This is because DOM parser actually uses some internal SAX parser under the hood to create the DOM model. However I'm sure on a relatively small XML the performance boost will not be worth time spent on coding.

> Are there any tools available to
>   measure the performance of
>   applications on a blackberry device?

Honestly I've never tried to find such tools. Usually I just use smth like:

```
final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// do smth ..
final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
log("passed for " + (end - start) + " ms"); // log() writes a message to SDCard
```

Comment: Thnx for the advice!! The incoming XML in this case would be of some KBs and definitely not in MBs. I suppose it would be safe to use the DocumentBuilderFactory API in this case. And I would definitely love to explore the Internet for some performance measurement tools for the mobile devices. In case I come across something, I'll let you know :-)